# Using Picasso to load an image into a bitmap

Tags: java, android, picasso

I`m tring to to load an image from an URL into a Bitmap using the Picasso library , but most of the examples i found refer to loading a Bitmap to a ImageView or something similar.

The code should be something like this , according to the documentation.

```
public void loadImage() {

        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("image url").into(new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom arg1) {
                Bitmap bitImage = Bitmap(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);
            }
            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
```

But `Bitmap bitImage = Bitmap(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);` doesn't seem to be correct, since i`m getting a Method call expected error.